# Using the akima bilinear function for interpolation

Tags: r

I am using the akima package and bilinear function to interpolate z values (temperatures) from a coarse coordinate grid (2.5° x 2.5°) to a finer grid (0.5° x 0.5°). The bilinear function works as follows:

**Usage**

bilinear(x, y, z, x0, y0)

**Arguments**

x   a vector containing the x coordinates of the rectangular data grid.

y   a vector containing the y coordinates of the rectangular data grid.

z   a matrix containing the z[i,j] data values for the grid points (x[i],y[j]).

x0  vector of x coordinates used to interpolate at.

y0  vector of y coordinates used to interpolate at.

**Value**

This function produces a list of interpolated points:

x   vector of x coordinates.

y   vector of y coordinates.

z   vector of interpolated data z.

Given the following data:

```
# coarse grid longitudes     x -> c(0, 2.5, 5, 7.5, 10)
# coarse grid latitudes      y -> c(50, 55, 60, 65, 70)
# temperatures               z -> c(10.5, 11.1, 12.4, 9.8, 10.6)
# fine grid longitudes       x0 -> c(0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2)
# fine grid latitudes        y0 -> c(50, 50.5, 51, 51.5, 52)
```

I tried the function:

```
bilinear -> (x=x, y=y, z=z, x0=x0, y0=y0)
```

But I get the following:

```
Error in if (dim(z)[1] != nx) stop("dim(z)[1] and length of x differs!") : 
argument is of length zero
```

I clearly don't fully understand how this function works and would really appreciate any suggestions if somebody knows what I'm doing wrong? I'm open to an alternative solution using a different package also.

Answer (score 0):

Read carefully the description of the function, z need to be a **matrix** with dimension x,y:

```
library(akima)
x <- c(0, 2.5, 5, 7.5, 10)
y <- c(50, 55, 60, 65, 70)
z <- matrix(rnorm(25), 5, 5)
x0 <- seq(0, 10, .5)
y0 <- seq(50, 70, length = length(x0))

> bilinear(x, y, z, x0, y0)
$x
[1]  0.0  0.5  1.0  1.5  2.0  2.5  3.0  3.5  4.0  4.5  5.0  5.5  6.0  6.5  7.0
[16]  7.5  8.0  8.5  9.0  9.5 10.0

$y
[1] 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70

$z
[1]  1.14880762  1.08789150  0.88252672  0.53271328  0.03845118 -0.60025959
[7] -0.13758256  0.17947029  0.35089894  0.37670342  0.25688371 -0.06736752
[13] -0.42197570 -0.80694083 -1.22226291 -1.66794194 -1.38940279 -1.08889523
[19] -0.76641923 -0.42197481 -0.05556197
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment Carlos. I am still struggling to adapt this to my situation. I have 5760 x values (longitude) and 5760 y values (latitude), so why are my z values not simply the 5760 data points (in this case temperatures) that correspond to the xy coordinates? I really don't seem to get what z is here and am finding any documentation more confusing.

Comment: You're dealing with spatial data, i.e. data (z) distributed in a surface (two linear coordinates - x and y). Even if your data correspond to a line (samples from a transect, for example), you're still dealing with a 2D grid in respect to the interpolation: bilinear interpolation will consider the four adjacent points. Take a look here, it may help: https://gisgeography.com/raster-resampling/